# Function overloading gives error: call to overloaded function is ambiguous

Tags: c++, overloading

I am trying to overload my function pointer_move for two different purpose. I overloaded it by number of arguments but it is still giving error that call to function(overloaded) is ambiguous. please help me solving the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* pointer_move(int *arr, int index, int current_position=0) {

    if(current_position < index) {
        while(current_position != index) {
            arr++;
            current_position++;
        }
        return arr;
    } else if(current_position > index) {
        while(current_position != index) {
            arr--;
            current_position--;
        }
        return arr;
    } else {
        return arr;
    }
}

int* pointer_move(int *arr, int element, int* null, int current_position=0) {

    if(current_position < element) {
        while(current_position < element) {
            arr++;
            current_position++;
        }
        return arr;
    } else if(current_position > element) {
        while(current_position > element) {
            arr--;
            current_position--;
        }
        return arr;
    } else {
        return arr;
    }
}

int main() {

    int x[5]={1,32,123,2321,14356};

    int *xp=x;
    xp=pointer_move(xp, 3);
    cout << *xp << endl;

    xp=x;
    xp=pointer_move(xp, 5, NULL);
    cout << *xp << endl;

}
```

Comment: I'm guessing `xp=pointer_move(xp, 5, nullptr);` would fix it. Your problem is that `NULL` is just `0` and `0` is valid as either an integer or a pointer. It's a legacy of C.

Comment: thank you, nullptr has fixed my problem, you guess right.

Comment: @john - There's an answer section bellow. If you find yourself editing details into your comment, it's kinda a sign it doesn't belong as a comment.